# GLSL shader class framerate issues

Tags: c++, glsl, shader

**VC++ 2010, SDL, OpenGL, GLSL**

I am working on this class as a way to switch between shaders quick and easily. It seems to be working properly(functionality-wise), however the framerate drops severely after implementing it(from 60 to 40). Hopefully you guys can point me in the right direction.

Here is what I have so far:

```
namespace SL {

struct Shader_Manager {

    struct shader_vect {

        GLuint      shader_type;
        GLuint      shader_handle;
        char *      filename;
    };

    struct search_vect
    {
        std::string target;
        bool operator()(const shader_vect& vect) const
        {
            return vect.filename == target;
        }
    };

    GLuint          prog;
    std::vector     <shader_vect> shader_list;

    GLuint          vertex_shader;
    GLuint          fragment_shader;

    Shader_Manager() {

        prog = glCreateProgram();
    };

    ~Shader_Manager() {};

    void load(char * filename, int type) {

        shader_vect shader;

        shader.filename             = filename;
        shader.shader_type          = type;

        shader.shader_handle        = glCreateShader(type);
        char * fs                   = textFileRead(filename);

        const char * vv = fs;
        glShaderSource(shader.shader_handle, 1, &vv, NULL);

        free(fs);
        glCompileShader(shader.shader_handle);

        shader_list.push_back(shader);
    }

    void use(char * filename) {

        search_vect search;
        search.target = filename;

        std::vector<shader_vect>::iterator it = 
                std::find_if(shader_list.begin(), shader_list.end(), search);

        glAttachShader(prog, it->shader_handle);

        glLinkProgram(prog);
        glUseProgram(prog);
    }

    void end() {

        glLinkProgram(0);
        glUseProgram(0);
    }
};
} // namespace SL
```

inside my main function I use it like such:

```
SL::Shader_Manager SLManager;
SLManager.load("shader.frag", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
```

and withing the game loop I am doing:

```
SLManager.use("shader.frag");
  makeSphere();
SLManager.end();
```

Am I not properly free'ing up some resources? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking a program every time you switch is a mistake. You should create as many programs as you need, all shader objects and then link everything that you will need. Then just call `glUseProgram` on a switch (possibly have a debug mode that calls `glGet(GL_CURRENT_PROGRAM)` and alerts for unnecessary switches, because those are, essentially, bugs.

Comment: Ah, ok so store separate programs for each one, attach necessary shaders to that program, possibly give it a name, and then just switch the program. Question: How do I disable to program? (stop it's use?)

Comment: How does it know which program I am referring to?

Comment: @Headspin Why would it need to know that? There is only one currently active program ever. `glUseProgram(0)` will simply tell the GL: "don't use any program for the rendering to come".

Comment: Ah, yes of coarse. Thanks for the help, Ill try to adjust this code and see if I cant get it working.

Comment: @Headspin Even though it sometimes feels unnatural to a C++ program, you should try to stay close to the OpenGL C API and keep the lower level object layers thin. Have higher level constructs to implement the actual rendering techniques.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I am learning C/C++ and OpenGL simultaneously. I probably get ahead of myself with a lot of OO approaches.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5551/discussion-between-pmr-and-headspin)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be constantly linking/using shaders every loop iteration. Only do so when you need to switch from one to another.

```
SLManager.use("shader.frag");
loop {
  makeSphere();
}
SLManager.end();
```

Also, don't use strings to refer to shaders. Create objects and pass them into the manager.